# Im trying to re write a txt file using jtable in java but it deletes the first line everytime

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im trying to rewrite dat in my text file by the code below

```
private void updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try{
        File file = new File ("logindata.txt");
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.getRowCount(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< datatable.getColumnCount(); j++){
                bw.write(datatable.getModel().getValueAt(i,j)+",");
            }
            bw.write("\n");
        }
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
       }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, please retry");
    }
}
```

here is the modify function in the GUI

```
private void modifybtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int i = datatable.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)datatable.getModel();
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        model.setValueAt(newusername.getText(), i, 0);
        model.setValueAt(newpass.getText(), i, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
}
```

code to view text file in jtable

```
private void viewbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logindata.txt"));
        String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
        String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(",");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)datatable.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
        model.setRowCount(0);
       
        Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
        {
            String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
            model.addRow(dataRow);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ep){
        Logger.getLogger(people_info.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ep);
    }
}
```

when I run it does modify the content in the text file but the first line always deletes. how can I stop this?

[image: before modification]

[image: after modification]

Comment: How is `modifybtnActionPerformed` related to `updateActionPerformed` ? Please post [mre]

Comment: `modifybtnActionPerformed` updates the form in GUI only then `updateActionPerformed` saves data from the jtable to txt file @c0der

Comment: _Im trying to re write a txt file using jtable in java but it deletes the first line_ I doubt if that is an accurate problem statement. You may still have the problem after removing the writting-to-file code. An mre is not only helpful for getting help here, but also as a good debugging tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the first line always deletes.

When you write the file you only write out the data.

```
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.getRowCount(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< datatable.getColumnCount(); j++){
            bw.write(datatable.getModel().getValueAt(i,j)+",");
        }
        bw.write("\n");
    }
```

But when you read the file you assume the first line is the column headers:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("logindata.txt"));
    String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
    String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(",");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)datatable.getModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
```

So the first line of the data is now treated as the column header.

You need to change the "write" method to write the "column headers" AND the "data".